# React router change protocol

Tags: reactjs, protocols, react-router

I have an application running with `react 15.3` and `react-router 4.0.0`. Routing uses a `link` from `react-router` library to match components to actual url.

The case I am trying to figure out is how to change the protocol without reloading page. Eg.

`http://example.org/foo` to `https://example.org/foo` 
(or even from `http://example.org/` to `https://example.org/foo`)
and awry

I've tried to `<Link to={'https://example.com/foo} />` but it doesn't work.  It seems like `Link to` works on relative paths.

Any ideas?

Comment: http -> https is handled server side (nginx or similar) - you should use relative paths in your react router

Comment: @Kunkka well I need just one link over https (the login form) any other can run over http. So the redirect on nginx doesn't solve the problem. I'd like to change the protocol without refresh the page.

Comment: you can always redirect http /login to https /login via nginx. this is the only way i know of unfortunately. you could try using a direct <a> tag instead of using the <link> from react-router. but i'm not sure if thats the solution